# How can I add support for Swiss German input in 18.04? There was no option during installation

Tags: 18.04, language-support, input-language

How can I install Swiss German keyboard support - I've only got the GERMAN keyboard.

There was no choice of German Swiss during the installation (as there was in earlier versions).

Comment: Which installer did you use? are you still interesting in finding that in the installer or in the installed system (or both)?

Comment: Hi pim  - thanks a lot for your explanations. In the meantime I had to reinstall LTS 18.04 because of other reasons. This time I saw the option to choose the swiss kbd. Sorry for bringing this up - was my mistake...   Kind Regards  Roland

Answer (score 6):

**During the installation**

After choosing the language:
On the left tab : `Switzerland` on the right tab : `Switzerland - German (Switzerland, no dead keys).`

**After installation, for the console**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then

- `Generic 105-key (Intl) PC`
- `Switzerland`
- `Switzerland - German (Switzerland, eliminate dead keys)`
- `The default for the keyboard layout`
- `No compose key`

Then **reboot** (or type `setupcon` in every console).

**After the installation for the GUI (ubuntu - gnome-shell)**

`Activities` > `Settings` > `Region & Language` > `Input Sources` > `+` > `German (Switzerland)` > `Add`

Then move up your language input or remove the others you don't want.

**After the installation for the GUI (xbubuntu - xfce)**

`Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Layout`, un-check `Use system default`, `Add`, `German (Switzerland)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did (and it worked):

- Run

  ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
  ```
- Select `de_CH.UTF-8`
- Go to keyboard layout
- Select `swiss german`